# Blender 3.1 Node Wrangler preview not working

Tags: node-editor

I have Node Wrangler enabled in Blender 3.1 on Windows 10 on a Mac laptop with numpad emulation. With a texture node, e.g. Gradient Texture selected, I press Ctrl and Shift and I see an icon in the lower left hand corner of the shader editor show the left mouse button with the text "Preview Node". I click and nothing happens. Why?

I have tried uninstalling all previous versions of Blender, deleted the Roaming/Blender preferences folders and completely reinstalled Blender 3.1 to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. You have to click ON the node in question. Even though it seems like it should be creating a node where you click, but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem with 3.2 alpha and it was solved after *reading* your answer. I'm not sure it was solved by disabling then enabling node wrangler or by your seemingly obvious *where to click* but it's ok now.

Comment: Of course it requires you to click the node you want to preview: previewing a node is not about adding a node in the first place. You are not asking to add a node somewhere, you are asking to preview a specific node that's already there. Node Wrangler's preview is just plugging whatever node you want into the material output, and **optionally** pass it through an emission shader **if the node you clicked isn't a shader itself**. And you can click several times on the same node to circle through its different outputs.